# Any Wrong with $get command here.. no error diplayed so do no result displayed

Tags: php, mysql

No Error in Cpanel but nothing show in browser..

About my code, i need display $result of status by directly from browser "http://www.example.com/exp.php?status=pending" to show table off all pending.. but when i execute in browser only showing ""

i'm completely new in coding.. those code i get from online and sewing to get my application..

Any help will be very appreciated..
Thanks in advance

```
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php

session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['uname']){
 header('Location: ../index.php');
          }
require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";         

if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = :status";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':status', $status);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
    exit;
}
?>

<?php  
if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
    if ($result->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
        <h2>Results</h2>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>kode</th>
                    <th>imei</th>
                    <th>nama</th>
                    <th>tipe</th>
                    <th>kerusakan</th>
                    <th>harga</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                    <th>alasan</th>
                    <th>perubahan</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["kode"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["imei"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["nama"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["tipe"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["kerusakan"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["harga"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["alasan"]); ?> </td>
                <td><a href="tutupservis.php?kode=<?php echo escape($row["kode"]); ?>">UPDATE</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <blockquote>No results found for <?php echo escape($_POST['status']); ?>.</blockquote>
    <?php } 
} ?> 


<a href="index.php">Kembali</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Only showing "templates/header.php"
I expect result to be shhowing in row of pending status

Comment: First thing I would do is `echo $_GET['status'];` and see if it contains anything. If these are being set from a form `isset()` won't be reliable, as this function will return true for empty strings.

Comment: And the big thing that I'm now seeing is that `session_start();` will never work in this code. It needs to be declared before the first byte at the very top of your code. Once a single character is rendered `session_start()` will not work. Start your session before loading the header

Answer (score 1):

i have fix the problem by trial and error..
here is the code that showing my result..
thank for helping

The solution is changing 
$result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
to 
$result = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

```
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['uname']){
 header('Location: ../index.php');
          }
require "../config.php";
require "../common.php";         

if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
  try {
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $status = $_GET['status'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = :status";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':status', $status);
    $statement->execute();

    $result = $statement->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $error) {
      echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
  }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong!";
    exit;
}
?>
<?
if (isset($_GET['status'])) {
    if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) { ?>
        <h2>Results</h2>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>harga</th>
                    <th>status</th>
                    <th>alasan</th>
                    <th>perubahan</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>                
                <td><?php echo escape($row["harga"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["status"]); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo escape($row["alasan"]); ?> </td>
                <td><a href="tutupservis.php?kode=<?php echo escape($row["kode"]); ?>">UPDATE</a></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <blockquote>No results found for <?php echo escape($_POST['status']); ?>.</blockquote>
    <?php } 
} ?> 


<a href="index.php">Kembali</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: If you're completely new to coding you should read some manals and understand some fundamental logics and [best practise](https://phpbestpractices.org/) before simply copy/pasting code. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

your code doesn't seem to have a problem. I don't know, but

```
if (isset($_GET["status"]))
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First, establish that `$_GET['status']` in your code is really getting data as desired so that you don't have to worry about that in processing it.

Start your php file with:

```
<?php
$status=$_GET['status'];
echo $status;
```

If that is displaying the data you meant for it, comment out the first two lines and proceed to build rest of your code. No result even after you verified the data through $_GET will point  you in the right direction.